# Como implementar o padrão de projeto Factory no VBA?

Tags: vba, factory

Gostaria de alguma metodologia ou exemplo para tentar simular a aplicação do padrão do projeto Factory no VBA.

Comment: Nossa, nunca achei que veria padrão de projeto e VBA na mesma frase.

Answer (score 2):

Estou usando o exemplo do livro  "Use a Cabeça - Padrões de Projeto", qué o de uma pizzaria.

Eu tenho usado duas abordagens para para ter Fachory Method no VBA:

1) Que usa uma coleção para evitar o uso de muitos IF's aninhados
   mas para isso todas as interfaces de criação que eu uso precisam ter o mesma assinatura.

2) Crio uma interface que seleciona as minhas interfaces de criação, assim consigo ter o método de fábrica cujos objetos podem ter métodos de criação com assinaturas diferentes, além de evitar o uso de muitos IF's aninhados.

**Primeira abordagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui eu crio a interface IPizza, onde todas as pizzas devem implementá-la.

```
'todas as pizzas implementam IPizza
Property Get getNome() As String: End Property
Property Get getIngredientes() As String: End Property
Property Get getPreco() As Double: End Property
```

Depois eu isolo a o método para criar uma pizza em outra interface. Nesta abordagem, cada classe de Pizza deve implementar a sua interface de criação de pizza. No exemplo nos temos clsPizzaCalabresa e clsPizzaQueijo, que implementam respectivamente ICriarPizzaCalabresa e ICriarPizzaQueijo.

classe: ICriarPizzaCalabresa

```
'a classe clsPizzaCalabresa deve implementar ICriarPizzaCalabresa
Function criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, ByVal ingredientes As String, ByVal preco As Double) As IPizza: End Function
```

classe: ICriarPizzaQueijo

```
'a classe clsPizzaQueijo deve implementar ICriarPizzaQueijo
Function criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, ByVal ingredientes As String, ByVal preco As Double) As IPizza: End Function
```

Observe elas possuem a mesma assinatura e que retornam **a mesma interface IPizza**.

Faltou o módulo padrão, do tipo Enum.

O módulo padrão do tipo Enum, modEnumPizza fica assim:

```
Public Enum enumTypePizza

    CALABRESA
    QUEIJO

End Enum
```

A classe clsPizzaCalabresa fica assim:

```
Implements IPizza
Implements ICriarPizzaCalabresa

Private Type TType
    nome As String
    ingredientes As String
    preco As Double
End Type

Private this As TType


'interface para a criação de uma pizza de Calabresa
Private Function ICriarPizzaCalabresa_criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, ByVal ingredientes As String, ByVal preco As Double) As IPizza

    With this

        .nome = nomeDaPizza
        .ingredientes = ingredientes
        .preco = preco

    End With

    'retorno a referência da interface IPizza de uma instancia clsPizzaCalabresa
    Set ICriarPizzaCalabresa_criar = Me

End Function

Private Property Get IPizza_getNome() As String
    IPizza_getNome = this.nome
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getIngredientes() As String
    IPizza_getIngredientes = this.ingredientes
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getPreco() As Double
    IPizza_getPreco = this.preco
End Property
```

E por fim, a classe clsPizzaQueijo:

```
Implements IPizza
Implements ICriarPizzaQueijo

Private Type TType
    nome As String
    ingredientes As String
    preco As Double
End Type

Private this As TType


'interface para a criação de uma pizza de Queijo
Private Function ICriarPizzaQueijo_criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, ByVal ingredientes As String, ByVal preco As Double) As IPizza

    With this

        .nome = nomeDaPizza
        .ingredientes = ingredientes
        .preco = preco

    End With

    'retorno a referência da interface IPizza de uma instancia clsPizzaQueijo        
    Set ICriarPizzaQueijo_criar = Me

End Function

Private Property Get IPizza_getNome() As String
    IPizza_getNome = this.nome
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getIngredientes() As String
    IPizza_getIngredientes = this.ingredientes
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getPreco() As Double
    IPizza_getPreco = this.preco
End Property
```

Agora iremos ver como fica a classe Factory desta primeira abordagem:

```
Implements ICriarPizzaCalabresa
Implements ICriarPizzaQueijo

Private Type TType
    'Mas poderia ser um dicionário, Referencias => Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    objCollection As Collection

End Type

Private this As TType

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Dim objInterfacePizzaQueijo As ICriarPizzaQueijo
    Dim objInterfacePizzaCalabresa As ICriarPizzaCalabresa

    'estou obtendo a refencia da interface ICriarPizzaQueijo e ICriarPizzaQueijo
    'e guardando em variaveis
    Set objInterfacePizzaQueijo = Me
    Set objInterfacePizzaCalabresa = Me

    'para evitar o uso de IF's aninhados, uso uma colecao.
    'Mas poderia ser um dicionario
    Set this.objCollection = New Collection

    With this.objCollection

        'guardo as refencias nesta colecao, onde a chave eh do tipo Enum,
        'neste caso o enum QUEIJO e CALABRESA, do modulo 'modEnumPizza'
        .Add objInterfacePizzaQueijo, CStr(enumTypePizza.QUEIJO)
        .Add objInterfacePizzaCalabresa, CStr(enumTypePizza.CALABRESA)

    End With

    'as variaveis com as refencias as interfaces estao guardadas na colecao
    'e por isso nao precisamos mais delas
    Set objInterfacePizzaQueijo = Nothing
    Set objInterfacePizzaCalabresa = Nothing

End Sub


Function CriarPizza(ByVal enumPizza As enumTypePizza, ByVal nome As String, ByVal ingredientes As String, ByVal preco As Double) As IPizza

    Dim objInterface As Object

    Set objInterface = this.objCollection(CStr(enumPizza))

                        'Estamos chamando o metodo por ligacao tardia ('late binding')
                        'mas note que para isso todos os metodos das interfaces implementadas
                        'precisam ter a mesma assinatura
    Set CriarPizza = objInterface.criar(nome, ingredientes, preco)

End Function


Private Function ICriarPizzaCalabresa_criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, ByVal ingredientes As String, ByVal preco As Double) As IPizza

    Dim objPizza As clsPizzaCalabresa
    Dim objInterfacePizza As ICriarPizzaCalabresa

    Set objPizza = New clsPizzaCalabresa

    Set objInterfacePizza = objPizza

    Set ICriarPizzaCalabresa_criar = objInterfacePizza.criar(nomeDaPizza, ingredientes, preco)

    Set objPizza = Nothing
    Set objInterfacePizza = Nothing

End Function

Private Function ICriarPizzaQueijo_criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, ByVal ingredientes As String, ByVal preco As Double) As IPizza

    Dim objPizza As clsPizzaQueijo
    Dim objInterfacePizza As ICriarPizzaQueijo

    Set objPizza = New clsPizzaQueijo

    Set objInterfacePizza = objPizza

    Set ICriarPizzaQueijo_criar = objInterfacePizza.criar(nomeDaPizza, ingredientes, preco)

    Set objPizza = Nothing
    Set objInterfacePizza = Nothing

End Function
```

E para ver tudo isso funcionar, criamos o módulo padrão chamado modMain, que fica assim:

Módulo modMain:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim objPizza As IPizza
    Dim objFactory As Factory

    Set objFactory = New Factory

    Set objPizza = objFactory.CriarPizza(QUEIJO, "Pizza de Queijo", "mussarela, oregano, oleo de oliva, molho simples", 25.99)

    Debug.Print "Nome: " & objPizza.getNome
    Debug.Print "Ingredientes: " & objPizza.getIngredientes
    Debug.Print "Preco: " & objPizza.getPreco

    Debug.Print

    Set objPizza = objFactory.CriarPizza(CALABRESA, "Pizza de Calabresa", "Calabresa, cebola, oleo de oliva, oregano", 30.99)

    Debug.Print "Nome: " & objPizza.getNome
    Debug.Print "Ingredientes: " & objPizza.getIngredientes
    Debug.Print "Preco: " & objPizza.getPreco


End Sub
```

E a saída na janela imediata fica:

```
Nome: Pizza de Queijo
Ingredientes: mussarela, oregano, oleo de oliva, molho simples
Preco: 25,99

Nome: Pizza de Calabresa
Ingredientes: Calabresa, cebola, oleo de oliva, oregano
Preco: 30,99
```

Segue link para download do exemplo:
[Factory Method - Stackoverflow - PT-BR.xlsm](https://github.com/LuciusBR/Padroes-de-Projeto-com-VBA/blob/master/Factory%20Method%20-%20Stackoverflow%20-%20PT-BR.xlsm)

Fim da parte um

2) Crio uma interface que seleciona as minhas interfaces de criação, assim consigo ter o método de fábrica cujos objetos podem ter métodos de criação com 
assinaturas diferentes, além de evitar o uso de muitos IF's aninhados.

Refatorei o exemplo anterior adicionando pouca complexidade. A novidade é que agora temos que informar os ingredientes dentro classe Factory, além do preço ser em função do tamanho da pizza, que é do tipo Enum.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguem os módulos padrão.

módulo: modEnumTamanho

```
Public Enum enumTypeTamanho

    PEQUENA
    MEDIA
    GRANDE
    FAMILIA

End Enum
```

módulo: modMain

```
Sub Main()

    Dim objPizza As IPizza
    Dim objFactory As Factory

    Set objFactory = New Factory

    Debug.Print

    'Antes era assim: Set objPizza = objFactory.CriarPizza(CALABRESA, "Pizza de Calabresa", "Calabresa, cebola, oleo de oliva, oregano", 30.99)
    Set objPizza = objFactory.Fabricar.Calabresa("Pizza de Calabresa")

    Debug.Print "Nome: " & objPizza.getNome
    Debug.Print "Ingredientes: " & objPizza.getDescricao
    Debug.Print "Preco: " & objPizza.getPreco(GRANDE)

    Debug.Print

    'Antes era assim: Set objPizza = objFactory.CriarPizza(QUEIJO, "Pizza de Queijo", "mussarela, oregano, oleo de oliva, molho simples", 25.99)
    Set objPizza = objFactory.Fabricar.Queijo("Pizza de Queijo")

    Debug.Print "Nome: " & objPizza.getNome
    Debug.Print "Ingredientes: " & objPizza.getDescricao
    Debug.Print "Preco: " & objPizza.getPreco(PEQUENA)

End Sub
```

Agora seguem os módulos de classe.

interface: IPizza

```
'todas as pizzas implementam IPizza
Property Get getNome() As String: End Property
Property Get getDescricao() As String: End Property
Property Get getPreco(ByVal tamanho As enumTypeTamanho) As Double: End Property
```

interface: ICriarPizzaQueijo

```
Function Criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, dictIngredientes As Scripting.Dictionary, dictTamanhoPreco As Scripting.Dictionary) As IPizza: End Function
```

interface: ICriarPizzaCalabresa

```
Function Criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, dictIngredientes As Scripting.Dictionary, dictTamanhoPreco As Scripting.Dictionary) As IPizza: End Function
```

interface: ISelecioneInterface

```
Property Get Calabresa(ByVal nome As String) As IPizza: End Property
Property Get Queijo(ByVal nome As String) As IPizza: End Property
```

Agora seguem as classes das Pizzas

classe: clsPizzaCalabresa

```
'
'Adicione a referencia 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' em 'Ferramentas' => 'Referencias...'
'

Implements IPizza
Implements ICriarPizzaCalabresa

Private Type TType
    nome As String
    dictIngredientes As Scripting.Dictionary
    dictTamanhoPreco As Scripting.Dictionary
End Type

Private this As TType


Private Function ICriarPizzaCalabresa_criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, dictIngredientes As Scripting.Dictionary, _
                 dictTamanhoPreco As Scripting.Dictionary) As IPizza

    With this

        .nome = nomeDaPizza
        Set .dictIngredientes = dictIngredientes
        Set .dictTamanhoPreco = dictTamanhoPreco

    End With

    Set ICriarPizzaCalabresa_criar = Me

End Function


Private Property Get IPizza_getDescricao() As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim descricao As String

    descricao = ""
    For i = 0 To this.dictIngredientes.Count - 1

        If i <> this.dictIngredientes.Count - 1 Then
            descricao = descricao & this.dictIngredientes(i) & ", "
        Else
            descricao = descricao & this.dictIngredientes(i)
        End If

    Next i

    IPizza_getDescricao = descricao

End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getNome() As String
    IPizza_getNome = this.nome
End Property


Private Property Get IPizza_getPreco(ByVal tamanho As enumTypeTamanho) As Double
    IPizza_getPreco = this.dictTamanhoPreco(tamanho)
End Property
```

classe: clsPizzaQueijo

```
'
'Adicione a referencia 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' em 'Ferramentas' => 'Referencias...'
'

Implements IPizza
Implements ICriarPizzaQueijo

Private Type TType
    nome As String
    dictIngredientes As Scripting.Dictionary
    dictTamanhoPreco As Scripting.Dictionary
End Type

Private this As TType


Private Function ICriarPizzaQueijo_criar(ByVal nomeDaPizza As String, dictIngredientes As Scripting.Dictionary, _
                 dictTamanhoPreco As Scripting.Dictionary) As IPizza

    With this

        .nome = nomeDaPizza
        Set .dictIngredientes = dictIngredientes
        Set .dictTamanhoPreco = dictTamanhoPreco

    End With

    Set ICriarPizzaQueijo_criar = Me

End Function


Private Property Get IPizza_getDescricao() As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim descricao As String

    descricao = ""
    For i = 0 To this.dictIngredientes.Count - 1

        If i <> this.dictIngredientes.Count - 1 Then
            descricao = descricao & this.dictIngredientes(i) & ", "
        Else
            descricao = descricao & this.dictIngredientes(i)
        End If

    Next i

    IPizza_getDescricao = descricao

End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getNome() As String
    IPizza_getNome = this.nome
End Property


Private Property Get IPizza_getPreco(ByVal tamanho As enumTypeTamanho) As Double
    IPizza_getPreco = this.dictTamanhoPreco(tamanho)
End Property
```

E por a classe responsável por fabricar as Pizzas

classe: Factory

```
Implements ISelecioneInterface


Function Fabricar() As ISelecioneInterface

    Set Fabricar = Me

End Function


Private Property Get ISelecioneInterface_Calabresa(ByVal nome As String) As IPizza

    Dim objPizza As clsPizzaCalabresa
    Dim objInterfacePizza As ICriarPizzaCalabresa

    Dim dictTamanhoPreco As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dictIngredientes As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dictTamanhoPreco = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dictIngredientes = New Scripting.Dictionary

    With dictTamanhoPreco
        .Add enumTypeTamanho.PEQUENA, 20.99
        .Add enumTypeTamanho.MEDIA, 25.99
        .Add enumTypeTamanho.GRANDE, 35.99
        .Add enumTypeTamanho.FAMILIA, 45.99
    End With

    With dictIngredientes
        .Add .Count, "Calabresa"
        .Add .Count, "cebola"
        .Add .Count, "molho simples"
        .Add .Count, "mussarela"
        .Add .Count, "azeitona"
        .Add .Count, "orégano"
        .Add .Count, "pimenta calabresa"
    End With

    Set objPizza = New clsPizzaCalabresa

    Set objInterfacePizza = objPizza

    Set ISelecioneInterface_Calabresa = objInterfacePizza.Criar(nome, dictIngredientes, dictTamanhoPreco)

End Property

Private Property Get ISelecioneInterface_Queijo(ByVal nome As String) As IPizza

    Dim objPizza As clsPizzaQueijo
    Dim objInterfacePizza As ICriarPizzaQueijo

    Dim dictTamanhoPreco As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dictIngredientes As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dictTamanhoPreco = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dictIngredientes = New Scripting.Dictionary

    With dictTamanhoPreco
        .Add enumTypeTamanho.PEQUENA, 20.99
        .Add enumTypeTamanho.MEDIA, 25.99
        .Add enumTypeTamanho.GRANDE, 35.99
        .Add enumTypeTamanho.FAMILIA, 45.99
    End With

    With dictIngredientes
        .Add .Count, "Mussarela"
        .Add .Count, "parmesão"
        .Add .Count, "gorgonzola"
        .Add .Count, "catupiry"
        .Add .Count, "molho simples"
        .Add .Count, "tomate"
        .Add .Count, "orégano"
    End With

    Set objPizza = New clsPizzaQueijo

    Set objInterfacePizza = objPizza

    Set ISelecioneInterface_Queijo = objInterfacePizza.Criar(nome, dictIngredientes, dictTamanhoPreco)

End Property
```

Agora basta executar o modMain, 'método' Main e veremos na janela imediata:

```
Nome: Pizza de Calabresa
Ingredientes: Calabresa, cebola, molho simples, mussarela, azeitona, orégano, pimenta calabresa
Preco: 35,99

Nome: Pizza de Queijo
Ingredientes: Mussarela, parmesão, gorgonzola, catupiry, molho simples, tomate, orégano
Preco: 20,99
```

Recomendo usar esta última abordagem.

Segue o link do planilha deste exemplo:

[Factory Method 2 - Stackoverflow - PT-BR](https://github.com/LuciusBR/Padroes-de-Projeto-com-VBA/blob/master/Factory%20Method%202%20-%20Stackoverflow%20-%20PT-BR.xlsm)